# Is it possible to ADD Hyperlink in Facebook Status Message or Photo album Message?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, message, status

> //Get album ID of the album you've just created $album_uid =
>   $create_album['id'];    //Upload a photo to album of ID...
>
> $file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file
>
> $photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Are you Good or Evil? 
>   ===>http://www.facebook.com/ithefunpage', 'image' => '@' . realpath($file) ); $upload_photo =
>   $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
>
> $upphoto = $upload_photo['id'];

---

I have this code above and it will create an album to the user with the status message  "Are you Good or Evil? ===> http://www.facebook.com/ithefunpage" now i just want to ask if it is possible to hyperlink the url "http://www.facebook.com/ithefunpage" into "Personality Quiz" or should i say is it possible to add hyperlink in facebook status message or Photo uplaod message?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. I'm pretty sure about that. and even the link in `message` is against facebook's t&c as far as I know.
Previously facebook status has an option to add ONE hyperlink in a special way, but now it is deprecated.